# how to scale a dataset contains a b&w and Grayscale images

Tags: deep-learning, data-cleaning, image-preprocessing, image

I have a dataset that contain both black and white images and a grayscale images (some of them are scnned by printer and other by camera and changes into gray)

how can make or scale my dataset so I can use it to feed a model ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\hat{p}=2\big(\frac{p}{p_{max}}\big)-1$ so that $\hat{p}\in [-1,1]$ where $p\in[0,p_{max}]$

E.g. with 8-bit channels, $p_{max}=255$, black/white correspond to $-1$ and $1$ respectively, and grayscale is linearly mapped in $[-1,1]$.

Comment: Thanks, I'm changing the gray scale into threshold black and white abd it worked--- using 
----


cv2.threshold(grayImage, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)